# How to change Windows Installer service permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, service

I'm about to run CI service as a custom user account.
The issue I faced is that Windows Installer service is allowed to run only by Administrators, INTERACTIVE/SERVICE accounts, or TrustedInstaller: https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/24361610/

Is there any way to add a specific user as allowed to run the service?
(Tried with Process Explorer, but on Windows it seem you are not an Administrator enough to change this service permissions ...)

I really would like to not set this account as an Administrator - as it's workaround for the issue, but breaks the security.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not directly possible. Software installation is a Admin Task.

Depending on the software, you need write permissions in various locations where users may not have access.

There are workarounds like installing Access Director, which can elevate users rights for a limited amount of time.

You can also use more advanced features like [Windows installer advertisement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/advertisement?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: The CI Current task is not to install the software, but to verify the generated msi packages.
So I'm not sure if such technique will do the job?

Comment: If you simply need to verify a MSI why not just CRC-it (something like MD5) ?

Comment: The verification process is not simply the CRC checking: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/error217/

Comment: That seems to be a package related problem. Should of been fixed officially.

Comment: What exact package do you mean?